# Disable USB power for USB controlled power strip

Tags: usb, power-management

I have a USB controlled power strip that has a single usb port.

[image]

If my computer is turned on and connected via usb to the power strip, the power strip will provide electricity to all the sockets. I want to programatically disable power to the usb port on the computer which is connected to the power strip.

This does not work:

```
$ echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/level
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Is there some other way to do this?
I would like to be able to connect to my server from somewhere else and turn off power to all the devices connected to the power sockets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the power strip do anything beyond read the +5V a connected USB port provides? (Do you see anything in `dmesg` when you attach it? Does the output of `lsusb` change after you plug it in?) If not, the kernel may not even recognize that anything is attached. You can't tell a device to suspend if it never enumerates itself: it would never show up under /sys/bus/usb/devices, and with USB you suspend devices, not ports.

Additionally, from `Documentation/usb/power-management.txt`:

```
 power/control

            This file contains one of two words: "on" or "auto".
            You can write those words to the file to change the
            device's setting.

            "on" means that the device should be resumed and
            autosuspend is not allowed.  (Of course, system
            suspends are still allowed.)

            "auto" is the normal state in which the kernel is
            allowed to autosuspend and autoresume the device.

            (In kernels up to 2.6.32, you could also specify
            "suspend", meaning that the device should remain
            suspended and autoresume was not allowed.  This
            setting is no longer supported.)
```

So according to that last little statement, if you have a kernel newer than 2.6.32 it sounds like you cannot force a USB device to suspend anyway.

Sorry that I can't give you the answer you actually wanted, what you were trying to do sounds pretty neat, but I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The power strip seems to work only by detecting the +5V - it does not seem to have any logic inside. Also, the `lsusb` does not show the power strip. I was fearing that something like this might be the case. I thought it may be possible to control other electrical devices by shutting down the voltage for the power strip USB. Perhaps there is a controllable usb-switch that can be bought somewhere, hm...

Answer (score 5):

```
# To enforce suspend immediately when device is unused:
echo -n "0" >$DEV_POWER_PATH"/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
echo -n "auto" >$DEV_POWER_PATH"/power/control"
# Make the device was not used
rmmod drv_name # see result of lsmod

# Power on: 
echo -n "2000" >$DEV_POWER_PATH"/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
echo -n "on" >$DEV_POWER_PATH"/power/control"
# Make the device was used.
modprobe drv_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I did have the same issue on my side.
a ls -al showed that only root have write access

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K May  8 10:27 level
```

So I tried to do the same command with sudo but I still had the same error

The only way I found to make it works was to do a chmod on this file then to write into it. Also. On my side control and autosuspend_delay_ms was not sufficient. I had to unbind it to be able to really suspend it.

```
sudo chmod 777 /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/power/control
sudo chmod 777 /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
sudo chmod 777 /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/power/control"
echo "0" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
echo -n "2-1.7" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Patrice for your solution, that one worked for me. The only problem that I had was that I couldn't figure out how to restart the device! Trying to just reverse the process with

```
echo "on" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/power/control"
echo "2000" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.7/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
echo -n "2-1.7" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

did not work. Finally, the only thing that I was able to get to do it was to reset the entire USB bus using the C code ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0) and this seems to force it to restart. This is done by compiling the code found [here](https://gist.github.com/x2q/5124616) (i.e. with gcc usbreset.c -o usbreset) and running it on bus #2 in this case.

```
usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/001
```

By doing this all of the devices on bus 2 seem to come back with their default properties set.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a hub and turn of power to that hub, the hub will then not have its own powerbrick connected. As long as it behaves like a device according to one of the posts above it should be possible to turn the hub off.

But I'd be weary to actually (accidentally) have anything USB like on any other port powered by the strip, because they will not get properly unmounted.

Might be useful to have a way to turn off the power to the computer turning off the power strip. But right now I cannot come up with a good scenario.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb* ; do echo "suspend" > $i/power/level; done
```

For debugging purposes, you can add an "echo $i" in there somewhere to let you know which devices are being hit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this just outputs the "Invalid argument" error message for all five usb devices.

Comment: Hmm. That makes it seem like the usb ports don't accept that command. Which kernel are you running? (uname -r)

Comment: I am running 2.6.38-8-generic-pae. I've read somewhere that the "suspend" feature was disabled for this kernel.

Comment: I wonder if the ports would turn off if you unloaded the device driver. Kind of drastic, but...

Comment: Is it possible to load/unload the device driver for the usb dynamically, without rebooting? Is there a way to do it on a per-port basis?

Comment: You can unload kernel modules with modprobe -r <name-of-driver>, as root. Per port, no.